# `const a:symbol = Symbol('a')` can't work in typescript

Tags: typescript

I use `const a:symbol = Symbol('a')` to create a symbol constant in typescript but it throws an error saying:

> 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to es2015 or later.

However, I have configured the `tsconfig.json` like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["es6"]
  }
}
```

Why it still throws an error?

Comment: [I can reproduce it in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noLib=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLggTwLYCMQBsYF4YDKamWAFAORzkCUQA). I had to enable the `noLib` compiler option, since the playground doesn't allow setting `lib` - you can set `target`, however. At any rate, this suggests that your TS configuration doesn't respect the `lib` option for some reason. I'm not sure *why* but it's what seems to be happening.

Comment: @VLAZ I used `tsc --init` to produce the config.json and changed the `target` to `es6` but it still didn't work. And when I run `tsc xxx.ts --target es6`, it worked. It seems the compiler didn't read the configuration from the config file.

Comment: Weird. Might be trying to read it from a different directory. But again I'm not sure why that would be.

Comment: @VLAZ I found the reason in the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). Because I use `tsc xxx.ts` to compile the file. In this case, it won't read the config file from the current path, which means `tsconfig.json` will be ignored. To solve this problem, just use `tsc` is enough.

Comment: OK, now that you mentioned it, I *have* actually seen this error before. I'd honestly consider it a bug yet it's documented behaviour. It seems like a something the TS team do not want to fix.